# Hearthstone Ranks, being stuck!

Tags: hearthstone

In hearthstone I'm stuck on the platinum rank, I only have 1 star, I've won 50 games since then and still didn't progress to star 2 or even 3, am I doing something wrong? [image: Picture of the ranks I'm on the 6th one or the 4th last on]

Comment: How many losses have you had with those 50 wins? Their internal ranking system tries to keep you at about a 50% win rate.

Comment: I would say mine is higher, I have a 4:1 ratio win ratio

Comment: If that's the case, you should be promoted soon.

Comment: @Charkz That would be Platinum rank, and not silver with two swords :) I am in the same position, but with 3 stars.

Comment: @Sorean No ranking system that I'm aware of actively tries to keep you at any win rate.

Comment: @Decency every ELO ranking system tries to keep you at 50 percent win rate, with the exception of very skilled and very unskilled players. 50 percent winrate means your rating is accurate. If you have more or less, the system adjusts your rating (and therefore your opponents) until you approach 50 percent win/lose.

Comment: @Lawton Sorry, that's just wrong. Feel free to link to a source if you think otherwise.

Comment: @Decency It looks like you paly a number of competetive games. You should know then that if a player is at 50 percent win rate, they are referred to as being at "true elo". This is because if a player  plays a large number of games and is properly matched, they will eventually be pushed toward 50 percent win rate by the Elo system. Not only that, it should be obvious that there isn't an alternative. If the system did not try to move players toward a win rate, pro players would have 99 percent win rates and newbies 1 percent, but Pro players have 50-60 percent win rates in reality.

Comment: @Decency for example, challenger league of legends player Dyrus has a win rate of 58 percent.  If the system was not pushing him toward 50 percent he would obviously have a winrate in the high 90s because he is one of the top players in north america. The same is true of every competitive game, pro players consistently have a win rate fairly close to 50, as do pretty much all players in the game. This is because the system pushes you there by adjusting your rating (and therefore your opponents)

Comment: @Lawton Each individual game is balanced, not a player's overall winrate. I think your assumption that a top player in the world would automatically have a winrate in the 90's in a team game is very flawed. If the system wanted him to lose games, it could just match him with brand new players against veterans and guarantee that he loses. It doesn't do that- it just tries to make each individual game balanced. As a result, win rates over time for most players tend towards 50%, but not as a result of any direct forcing.

Comment: @Decency, if you look at the same thing with a single player (as opposed to team) game though, it works. The system doesn't actively try to manipulate things so that you end up losing if you have more than 50% win rate, no one says that. But the way the system is designed, it pushes you towards 50% in the long run. It really is pretty obvious: If you win a lot (>50%), you get paired against players with a higher rating than your own rating, supposedly leading to you losing to stronger opponents. If you still win, you keep getting better opponents until you start losing more. Basic control law.

Comment: @scenia Actually, a lot of people say that... it's a very common misconception. Look above- Lawton and Sorean above both think exactly that.

Comment: It's not a misconception. It's an immediate consequence of the system's design. The more you win, the stronger your opponents become, lowering the probability of you winning. As long as your win rate is still above 50%, your opponents will keep getting stronger until the probability of you winning is so low that your win rate will drop below 50%. Then the effect will be reversed. In the long run, you'll end up at roughly 50%, how close depends on the system's inertia and the amount of data available. This principle is called "closed loop" or "feedback loop" and is heavily used in engineering.

Comment: @scenia While your overall thought on the nature of the feedback loop is accurate, your comment on "lowering the probability of you winning" is wrong, and that's the misconception I'm addressing. The vast majority of matchmaking systems aim for EVERY match to give each side a 50% chance to win, and match players accordingly.

Comment: @scenia A player who is on a lengthy winning streak will still be expected to have approximately a 50% chance to win each and every game along that streak- even though he's matched against successively stronger opponents- because his expected absolute contribution to the game has also increased appropriately. At no point in time does any system that I'm aware of purposely weight things against players on winning streaks such that they're more likely to lose the game.

Comment: @Decency That depends on your definition of purposely. A player on a winning streak will keep getting stronger opponents, at some point opponents more skilled than himself. Due to his momentum/inertia climbing the ladder, he will pass the point of equally strong opponents and be paired against players above his own skill level. By pure laws of logic, his winning probability against such players is lower than against weaker players. I think our disagreement comes from you talking about what the system attempts (50% winning odds), while i address what the system actually does (odds <> 50%).

Comment: You guys are talking past each other. The game systems y'all mention try to match players with similar Elo scores, providing balanced matches. This results in players having balanced winrates. Both things happen. If your score goes up, the system will match you with better players. If the system matches you with better players, your chance of winning will decrease.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the issue come from the level of the opponent you won against. Currently there are not enough players in the game (Which is still in beta) to always find an opponent that allows you to rank up.

As posted by an admin on [http://us.battle.net/hearthstone](http://us.battle.net/hearthstone/en/forum/topic/9678848351#7)

> Matchmaking functions similar to SC2. You have a hidden rating that
>   rises and falls based on your wins and losses, and the amount it rises
>   and falls depends on the rating of the person you are matched with.
>
> As more people get invited to the Beta, you should see an even better
>   spread of people matched against you.

Comment: The matchmaking system is also a placeholder that is going to be reworked, so its not strange that it doesn't work too well. The details are available on the hearthstone website.

Comment: This is a good answer, but blizzard has announced a new system they are going to test out. The new system is stated to have 25 different leagues and the players in the top league will be able to see their rank within that league. There is a blue post on the forums about what they are looking to do. One other really interesting point is that you will be able to drop down leagues in the new system (unlike the current).

Answer (score -1):

All of your answers are wrong.

If you are not promoted it is because you do not have the mmr to do so. I built a paladin deck with basic cards and <5 rares
 and 1 epic (faceless manipulator) after receiving my beta key 5 days ago and have already gone to diamond 1 star before the changes today. I am fairly sure you are ranked for deck strength as well because my deck was horrible but I played smarter than others and was therefore promoted even if I didn't win all my games.

Comment: If you're referring to the "answers" given in the comments, most of them say exactly this. Being promoted depends on your internally tracked rating (elo, mmr, whatever you want to call it) reaching or exceeding some threshold. And the changes to that rating depend on the rating of the opponents you play against. You were probably simply lucky to meet the right (strong) opponents in random matchmaking.